# perpendicular geo distance from a point to a line using boost geometry

Tags: boost, geometry, gis, boost-geometry

I want to get perpendicular distance from a point `(t)` to a line segment `(p, q)`. The perpendicular may not intersect the line `[p, q]`. In that case I want to extend the line `(p, q)` hypothetically and then draw the perpendicular to get the distance. p, q, t are all gps coordinates. I am using boost geometry.

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::point<
    double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::spherical_equatorial<boost::geometry::degree>
> geo_point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::segment<geo_point> geo_segment;

geo_point p(88.41253929999999, 22.560206299999997);
geo_point q(88.36928063300775, 22.620867969497795);
geo_point t(88.29580956367181, 22.71558662052875);
```

I have plotted these three locations on [map](https://mapmakerapp.com/?map=5bdd908043002930667535e25696)
[image]

I measure two distances `qt` and distance from `t` to `pq`

```
double dist_qt = boost::geometry::distance(q, t);
std::cout << dist_qt*earth_radius << std::endl;

geo_segment line(p, q);
double perp_dist = boost::geometry::distance(t, line);
std::cout << perp_dist*earth_radius << std::endl;
```

Both of these distances are same. This means it doesn't calculate the perpendicular distance. Rather it calculated `shortest` distance from a point to a line within `bounds`.

How can I calculate the perpendicular distance in such a way so that it is necessarily perpendicular irrespective of bounds ?

Working Example in [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/4iw3)

Comment: [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=distance+point+line) discarding all answers for distance to segment (keep distance to line) The [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) shows many formulas for line (not segment)

Comment: Well most of the answers are based on euclidean distances. But I need real earth distance in meters. Actually what I need is the great circle distance from `t` a point on the extension of `(p, q)` which is again an arc because earth is approximately a sphere. It is easy if it is a Cartesian coordinate. But for GPS coordinates its not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer do all calculations, **without boost**.

---

Consider a sphere of radius R = 1.

[image]

Points A, B are on a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle). This great circle `gcAB` goes also through the center point **O** of the sphere (required for great circles). Points **A**, **B**, **O** define a plane `PL1`.

Point **P** also lies in a great circle.

The minimum distance (measured along the arc of a great circle, not along a 3D straight line) from **P** to the great circle `gcAB` is the length of the arc **PC**.

Plane **PL2** of great circle `gcPC` is perpendicular to the plane **PL1**.

We want point **C**, which lies in the line **OC**, which is the intersection of the two mentioned planes.

.

Plane **PL1** is defined by its perpendicular vector `pp1`. This vector is obtained by the *cross product* of vectors `OA` and `OB`.

Because the plane **PL2** is perpendicular to plane **PL1**, it must contain the vector `pp1`. So the perpendicular vector `pp2` to plane **PL2** can be obtained by the cross product of `OP` and `pp1`.

A vector `ppi` in the line `OC` intersection of both planes is obtained by the cross product of `pp1` and `pp2`.

If we *normalize* vector `ppi` and multiply its components by the radius `R` of Earth, we get the coordinates of point **C**.

Cross product is not commutative. This means that if we interchange points A,B we get the opposite point **C'** in the sphere. We can test distances `PC` and `PC'` and get their minimum.

---

To calculate the **great-circle distance** [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) for two points **A**, **B**, it relies on the angle `a` between the lines `OA` and `OB`.

For best accuracy on all angles we use `a = atan2(y, x)` where, using radius 1, `y= sin(a)` and `x= cos(a)`. `sin(a)` and `cos(a)` can be calculated by cross product (OA, OB) and *dot product* (OA, OB) respectively.

Putting all together we have this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

const double degToRad = std::acos(-1) / 180;

struct vec3
{
    double x, y, z;
    vec3(double xd, double yd, double zd) : x(xd), y(yd), z(zd) {}
    double length()
    {
        return std::sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
    void normalize()
    {
        double len = length();
        x = x / len;
        y = y / len;
        z = z / len;
    } 
};

vec3 cross(const vec3& v1, const vec3& v2)
{
    return vec3( v1.y * v2.z - v2.y * v1.z,
                 v1.z * v2.x - v2.z * v1.x,
                 v1.x * v2.y - v2.x * v1.y );
}

double dot(const vec3& v1, const vec3& v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z;
}

double GCDistance(const vec3& v1, const vec3& v2, double R)
{
    //normalize, so we can pass any vectors
    vec3 v1n = v1;
    v1n.normalize();
    vec3 v2n = v2;
    v2n.normalize();
    vec3 tmp = cross(v1n, v2n);
    //minimum distance may be in one direction or the other
    double d1 = std::abs(R * std::atan2(tmp.length() , dot(v1n, v2n)));
    double d2 = std::abs(R * std::atan2(tmp.length() , -dot(v1n, v2n)));

    return std::min(std::abs(d1), std::abs(d2));
}                  

int main()
{
    //Points A, B, and P
    double lon1 = 88.41253929999999  * degToRad;
    double lat1 = 22.560206299999997 * degToRad;
    double lon2 = 88.36928063300775  * degToRad;
    double lat2 = 22.620867969497795 * degToRad;
    double lon3 = 88.29580956367181  * degToRad;
    double lat3 = 22.71558662052875  * degToRad;

    //Let's work with a sphere of R = 1
    vec3 OA(std::cos(lat1) * std::cos(lon1), std::cos(lat1) * std::sin(lon1), std::sin(lat1));
    vec3 OB(std::cos(lat2) * std::cos(lon2), std::cos(lat2) * std::sin(lon2), std::sin(lat2));
    vec3 OP(std::cos(lat3) * std::cos(lon3), std::cos(lat3) * std::sin(lon3), std::sin(lat3));
    //plane OAB, defined by its perpendicular vector pp1
    vec3 pp1 = cross(OA, OB);
    //plane OPC
    vec3 pp2 = cross(pp1, OP);
    //planes intersection, defined by a line whose vector is ppi
    vec3 ppi = cross(pp1, pp2);
    ppi.normalize(); //unitary vector

    //Radious or Earth
    double R = 6371000; //mean value. For more precision, data from a reference ellipsoid is required

    std::cout << "Distance AP = " << GCDistance(OA, OP, R) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Distance BP = " << GCDistance(OB, OP, R) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Perpendicular distance (on arc) = " << GCDistance(OP, ppi, R) << std::endl;
}
```

Wich gives the distances
AP = 21024.4  BP = 12952.1 and  PC= 499.493 for the given three points.

Running code [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/C1mhI07L1dVwB5oi)

Comment: I suppose `GCDistance(OB, OP, R)` corresponds to my `qt` distance. Your answer is `15211.4 meters` I expected it to be close to `12950 meters`. Why qt distance is giving different result ?

Comment: @NeelBasu Arrrg. The 'dot' product was miscalculated. THX. I've update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use the `project_point` strategy:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d3bd4450edd4ae0)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

int main(){
    double const earth_radius = 6371.0; // Km

    typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::spherical_equatorial<bg::degree>> geo_point;
    typedef bg::model::segment<geo_point> geo_segment;

    geo_point p(88.41253929999999, 22.560206299999997);
    geo_point q(88.36928063300775, 22.620867969497795);
    geo_point t(88.29580956367181, 22.71558662052875);

    double dist_qt = bg::distance(q, t);
    std::cout << dist_qt*earth_radius << std::endl;

    geo_segment line(p, q);
    double perp_dist = distance(t, line, bg::strategy::distance::projected_point<>{});
    std::cout << perp_dist*earth_radius << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
12.9521
763.713
```

I didn't check the results (in that picture it seems slightly surprising that the perp_dist be so much larger), but perhaps I'm missing something.

In case you have to do special things (apart from the coordinate system) to get that "haversine" (I'm sorry I'm not up to speed with this), you might need to pass the second template argument to the [`projected_point`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/strategies/strategy_distance_projected_point.html) strategy: "*underlying point-point distance strategy*".

Comment: But the perpendicular distance should be smaller than `qt`

Comment: @NeelBasu I believe I told you this and what I know about it. If you don't think this answer is helpful, just ignore it.  If you knew about the  strategy I think it should have been in your question code.